# Cubic 3-edge connected graph which is neither hamiltonian nor hypohamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Is there such a thing as a cubic 3-edge connected graph which is neither hamiltonian nor hypohamiltonian? Intuition says yes, but I'd like a confirmation (and an example, if possible).

Thank you!

Comment: Not all [snarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snark_(graph_theory)#Properties) are hypohamiltonian...

Comment: Very true! Thank you :)

Comment: @vadim123 Better post your comment (with reference) as an answer